# Como validar se o valor de um formulário é igual o valor do outro no atributo 'validator' do TextFormField()

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá!

Tenho um componente _textFieldValue(), para não precisar ficar repedindo o mesmo código mais de uma vez.

1. **Componente _textFieldValue()**

```
Widget _textFieldValue(String title, TextEditingController controller) {
  return TextFormField(
    validator: (value){
      if(value.isEmpty) return 'Campo obrigatório';
      if(int.parse(value) < 0) return 'Informe um valor igual ou maior que 0.';
      return null;
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: controller,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: title,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    ),
  );
}
```

2. **Aplicando o _textFieldValue()**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. **View**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você pode observar, estou **fazendo validações do formulário**. E minha dúvida é, como posso validar se o valor digitado no primeiro campo ('Mínimo') é igual ao valor digitado no segundo campo ('Máximo').

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer que essa validação seja feita de dentro do método que você coloca em```validator```? Ou seja, quer receber o valor de um textfield dentro do outro? Ou essa validação pode ser feita fora?

Comment: Olá. Naslausky. Seria bom se fosse dentro do método, mas se não fosse possível poderia ser fora.

Comment: Se for dentro, o mesmo erro de validação vai acontecer duas vezes, uma em cada campo. Não é muito elegante, mas se for esse o desejado, você pode passar dois controllers como parâmetro para seu widget (ao invés de um) e comparar os valores com ```controller.value == outroController.value```. Se for isso mesmo que deseja eu escrevo uma resposta depois.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou perfeitamente. Só foi preciso mudar algumas coisas. Eu tirei o textFormField de um componente e coloquei direto no 'código principal'. E para fazer a validação de vez passar o controller.value, eu coloquei direto o _controllerMin.text == _controllerMax.text.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas cheque os valores dos controllers:

```
validator: (text) {
   if(text == outroController.value) {
     return null;
   } else {
     return 'não combinam';
   }
 }
```